# Setting up a shortcut for knitr chunk in Lyx

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

I'm new to Lyx and would very much like to set up a new shortcut for inserting a new Chunk (`Insert > Custom Insets > Chunk`)

I saw [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg93955.html) how to set one up, but this is not the same; the `Chunk` menu item from the `Custom Insets` doesn't require the `<<>>=` and `@` characters in the chunks.

Any help appreciated on how to (if possible) assign this command to a new shortcut.

Comment: See my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531

Comment: It worked, thanks. Do you think I should post further questions about Lyx on the tex site? Seems like a grey zone to me...

Comment: I agree that it's a grey zone. If the questions involve anything that requires knowledge of LaTeX (or related tools) then I would say yes. If it is more about the software (like this question), then I think here might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it, thanks to scottkosty's [instructions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208510/lyx-commands-to-insert-wysiwyg-horizontal-line-for-keyboard-shortcut/208531#208531) on tex.

Go to `Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts` and create a new shortcut entering the following text as the `function`:

`flex-insert "Chunk"`

Then, just assign a key combination to it and you're done.